# Alter Table in Stored Procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, alter-table

First time posting, please let me know if this question has already been answered! I tried searching around, but couldn't find anything.

In my stored procedure, I select into a temp table while I do some modifying (Ive dumbed it down to the basic issue).

```
SELECT 'a' AS ColA, 'b' AS ColB INTO #tmp

ALTER TABLE #tmp 
    ADD ColC char(5) NULL, 
        ColD char(5) NULL, 
        ColE char(5) NULL

UPDATE #tmp
SET ColC = 'c',
    ColD = 'd',
    ColE = 'e'
FROM #tmp

SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

In Query Analyzer, If you highlight & run them separately, in order, I get the desired output.

```
ColA ColB ColC  ColD  ColE
---- ---- ----- ----- -----
a    b    c     d     e
```

However, when I run them all together, I get the following error:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'colC'.
```

It looks like the ALTER TABLE statement is being skipped over?  I inserted GO statements after each command, and the code worked in query analyzer.  However, I cannot figure out how to replicate this in a stored procedure.  (Is there a "GO" equivalent for s-procs?)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I ran it against SQl 2005 and got the desired output without any error.

Comment: Forgot to note, Im stuck on SQL 2000 for this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GO is not part of T-SQL, it's a batch separator supported by a number of SQL Server tools.

You can generally do the ALTER TABLE with an EXEC, but if your problem requiring an ALTER immediately after a create was how to get dummy columns, then your specific example can simply be done:

```
SELECT 'a' AS ColA
    ,'b' AS ColB
    ,CAST(NULL AS char(5)) AS ColC
    ,CAST(NULL AS char(5)) AS ColD
    ,CAST(NULL AS char(5)) AS ColE
INTO #tmp

UPDATE #tmp
SET ColC = 'c',
    ColD = 'd',
    ColE = 'e'
FROM #tmp

SELECT * FROM #tmp
```